# The truth value of a is ambiguous when I used Iflese in Python

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I am using conditional multiplication within data frame and using following syntax:

```
if(df_merged1["region_id"]=="EMEA"):
    df_merged1["fcst_gr"] = df_merged1["plan_price_amount"]*(df_merged1["Enr"]-df_merged1["FM_f"])+df_merged1["OA_f"]-df_merged1["TX_f"]
else:
    df_merged1["fcst_gr"] = df_merged1["plan_price_amount"]*(df_merged1["Enr"]-df_merged1["FM_f"])+df_merged1["OA_f"]
```

i want tax to be substracted only when region is EMEA. but getting following error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I think there is some problem in proving the if condition but how to resolve it not getting any idea

Comment: Looks like `df_merged1["region_id"]` is a *column* of strings. Do you want to test if all of the rows in that column are equal to `"EMEA"`?

Comment: yes this column is string and not all entries are EMEA

Comment: Well, then `df_merged1["region_id"]=="EMEA"` isn't going to return a single Boolean value, right?

Comment: @Ashish that's why the if condition fails. Rather use a dictionary or a lambda function to create the new column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem here - `df_merged1["region_id"] == "EMEA"` returns a `pd.Series` instance populated with boolean values, not a boolean that can be handled using conditional statements. Pandas is reluctant to automatically run a method that would convert a `pd.Series` instance to a boolean like `pd.Series.any()` or `pd.Series.all()`, hence the error.

To achieve what you have meant to do, use [`np.where`](https://towardsdatascience.com/creating-conditional-columns-on-pandas-with-numpy-select-and-where-methods-8ee6e2dbd5d5). That way you populate a column `["fcst_gr"]` based on value in column `["region_id"]` for each individual row:

```
base = (
    df_merged1["plan_price_amount"] * (df_merged1["Enr"] - df_merged1["FM_f"])
    + df_merged1["OA_f"]
)
df_merged1["fcst_gr"] = np.where(
    df_merged1["region_id"] == "EMEA", base - df_merged1["TX_f"], base
)
```

Comment: thanks it worked what's the reason to use axis = 1?

Comment: Axis = 0 applies a function column-wise, axis = 1 - row-wise. Since your goal is to get a different value for column ["region_id"] depending on values in other columns you need to go row-by-row, hence axis =1.